# Issue When Running Gem Commands With RVM 1.16.8 & Ruby 1.9.3p194 - `load_api_keys': undefined method `key?'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I recently updated my Mac Mini to OS 10.8 Mountain Lion, and using Ruby gems with RVM 1.16.8, Ruby 1.9.3p194 no longer works.

Here is the concise version of the error:

```
`load_api_keys': undefined method `key?' for #<String:0x007f865a928a28> (NoMethodError)
```

When I run any command like `gem install bundler` or `gem -v` I get the error below:

```
➜  ~ gem
/Users/brettchalupa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:227:in `load_api_keys': undefined method `key?' for #<String:0x007f865a928a28> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/brettchalupa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:208:in `initialize'
from /Users/brettchalupa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `new'
from /Users/brettchalupa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `do_configuration'
from /Users/brettchalupa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
from /Users/brettchalupa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem:25:in `<main>'

➜  ~ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

➜  ~ rvm -v

rvm 1.16.8 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

I have gone in and commented out the conflicting method call `load_api_keys` which makes things function properly, but it then breaks any interaction with rubygems.org.

The issue is line :227, `if @api_keys.key? :rubygems_api_key then`

```
def load_api_keys
  @api_keys = if File.exist? credentials_path then
                load_file(credentials_path)
              else
                @hash
              end
  if @api_keys.key? :rubygems_api_key then
    @rubygems_api_key = @api_keys[:rubygems_api_key]
    @api_keys[:rubygems] = @api_keys.delete :rubygems_api_key unless @api_keys.key? :rubygems
  end
end
```

After removing RVM and attempting to install different Rubies, I have not found a solution to this issue. I do not want to simply comment out something that removes functionality that I use.

If anyone could give any insight as to what is causing this and how to fix it, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove (or move) /Users/brettchalupa/.gem/credentials and let it use the default credentials.

Comment: Removing the credentials file in ~/.gem/ fixed the issue. Thank you very much.